# Centos7 How to identify Network Device name for a kickstart file

Tags: centos, systemd, kickstart

When the Rhel/Centos 7 operating systems moved forward to systemd, network device name configuration changed to predictable network device names

There is an explanation for systemd's predictable netwrk device names at
[https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c#L20e](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c#L20)

After controlled installation, my network interface is named as enp0s3

en=Ethernet
p=bus and s=slot   — PCI geographical location

since this is a remote server, how can i identify p and s values for  kickstart file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to use the traditional `eth0` naming scheme. This suits single network interface servers very well. This method may not be a good idea for laptops or systems with many or dynamic network interfaces in which case you will need to deal with that complexity, somehow. In particular, the `ksdevice=eth0 net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0` options should make the server use `eth0`, and indicate to KickStart that `eth0` is the device, for example in an EFI grub configuration:

```
menuentry "centos7" {
        linuxefi /centos7/vmlinuz ks=.../ks/c7 ksdevice=eth0 net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0
        initrdefi /centos7/initrd.img
}
```

an older `pxelinux.cfg` file might instead contain something like

```
label centos7
         kernel centos7/vmlinuz
         append initrd=centos7/initrd.img ks=.../ks/c7 ksdevice=eth0 net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0
```

Then in the KickStart configuration file `.../ks/c7` you may need to include or generate appropriate configuration for the system, e.g.

```
bootloader --location=mbr --append="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
network --device=eth0 --bootproto=dhcp --ipv6=auto
```

Comment: This can cause problems later down the line, e.g. flipping mac addresses upon reboot, because the old naming scheme is becoming less and less supported.